# How to set WindowBuilder Editor as default in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno, windowbuilder

Does anyone know how I can set the WindowBuilder Editor as default editor for all (or some) *.java* files? I love WindowBuilder, but it's "a waste of time" to have to do `right click -> Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor`... I'm using Eclipse Juno. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if activating `Associate WindowBuilder editor with automatically recognized Java GUI files` in `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `WindowBuilder` works for you. It is disabled by default.

Another way would be to always open `.java` files with the WindowBuilder Editor. You can set this here: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `File Associations`.

Comment: Thanks bro! Tried with the first one, and it seemed like it didn't work, but then the other *.java* GUI files started to open as default with the WindowBuilder. Thanks!